# How to maintain data integrity using JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse data using `JSON.parse(response)` but the function is removing the trailing zeros because my data is coming through as numbers and not as `Strings`. I don't have any control over the data coming in and I need a way to keep the zeros.

Something like:

```
{"name":"apples","price":15.40 }
```

returns `15.4`. Is there a way to do this using `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: I assume you can't add the zero there yourself since you know it should have exactly two decimal places?

Comment: @Juhana I was hoping there'd be a way to maintain the data without getting fancy. Obviously there are work arounds. Plus I'd have to do that for every value, and I'd have to convert the int to a String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parseFloat(15.4).toFixed(2); //15.40
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 1):

[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function has one more parameter (reviver). It is function which controls how parsed data will be transformed. So that you can transform `price` property to the formatted string:

```
var data = '{"name":"apples","price":15.4 }';

var parsed = JSON.parse(data, function(key, value) {
    if (key === 'price') {
        return parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
    }
    return value;
});

console.log(parsed.price); // 15.40
```